# MongoDB dotted query works, elemMatch query doesn't

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, subquery, database

While

`collection.find({ "data.username": "someusername" }}})`

works, fetching 1 matched document, this

`collection.find({ data: { $elemMatch: { username: "someusername" }}})`

doesn't fetch anything. Shouldn't it? (I'd use dotted but want to expand the query.)

This is with the mongo console on a Meteor collection. Tried in Robomongo and Meteor consoles too, with same results.

***UPDATED***: Here's an example of a document (trimmed)

```
{
    "_id" : "fDyZsiuqQgkRmPno5",
    "type" : "user",
    "data" : {
        "id" : 1234,
        "username" : "someusername",
        "website" : "http://www.somewhere.com",
        "email" : null,
        "payments" : [ 
            {
                "payment" : {
                    "id" : "zFyZsiGgQskRmPn43"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-08-28T12:16:46.918+02:00")
}
```

Comment: As I said in my answer (even before your "edit")  you can't use `$elemMatch`  here because `data` is not an array field

Comment: I know. Marked as correct. I was just writing you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query didn't return any result because `data` is not an *array* field. This is the expected behavior see the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#definition)

> The `$elemMatch` operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

Comment: Thanks, accepted since that answers it. Wrapping data in brakets worked. A document won't have more than one data subdocument so would be great to know if there's an effective way to query for those with multiple criteria like $elemMatch.